# Проверка создания базы данных

Tags: android, база-данных

Я хочу убедиться, создается ли у меня база данных. По идее у меня должно открываться второе активити, в ней вписываются название заметки и сама заметка, а по клику назад эта инфа вносится в бд и активити закрывается, возвращая на основное

Код БД

```
class DataBaseTask extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DB_NAME = "taskApp";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

public DataBaseTask(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE TASK (" +
            "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + "NAME TEXT, "
            + "TASKTEXT TEXT)");
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}
}
```

Код в активити

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    Button buttonBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_back);

    final EditText editNameTask = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
    final EditText editTextTask = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_task);
    final String editName;
    final String editTask;
    editName = editNameTask.getText().toString();
    editTask = editTextTask.getText().toString();
    final Context context = this;




    buttonBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SQLiteDatabase dataBaseTask = new DataBaseTask(context).getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put("NAME", editName);
            contentValues.put("TASKTEXT TEXT", editTask);
            dataBaseTask.insert("TABLE", null, contentValues);

            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: `editName = editNameTask.getText().toString();` - в `onCreate` поля ещё пустые  перенесите получение текста туда, где он будет использоваться (`onClick`). А о чём вопрос то вообще? Поясните что у Вас не получается.

Answer (score 0):

Ручной способ проверки, создаётся ли база данных - в Android Studio на вкладке "Device File Explorer" (скриншот ниже) пройдите по пути:

data -> data -> имя вашего пакета (например com.example.myapp) -> databases -> имя вашей базы данных.

Если файла нет, значит что-то мешает созданию, если есть, можете сохранить файл (Ctrl + Shift + S), и открыть файл, например при помощи [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) (для простоты переименуйте файл, дописав в конце расширение .db или .sqlite). В этой программе можете посмотреть структуру таблиц и их содержимое.

Так же, можно проверить, например, таким методом:

```
Cursor cursor = dataBaseTask.query("TASK", null, null, null, null, null, null);
if (cursor.getCount() > 0)
    //в таблице есть данные
```

Ещё можно написать unti тест, проверяющий создание таблицы:

```
public boolean doesTableExist(String tableName) {
        //Учтите, что поле 'table' регистро-зависимо!
        String sql = "SELECT NAME FROM SQLITE_MASTER WHERE TYPE='table'";
        Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQueryRead(sql);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            if (cursor.getString(0).equals(tableName))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

P.S. Как справедливо заметил @woesss, вам нужно исправить ContentValues в методе `onClick(View v)` :

```
contentValues.put("NAME", editNameTask.getText().toString());
contentValues.put("TASKTEXT", editTextTask.getText().toString());
```

[image: Device file explorer]

Comment: По пути "data->data->com.example.taskapplication (имя моего проекта) находится строка, подсвеченная красным "could not set capabilities: Operation not permitted" Пользуясь переводчиком в ней написано "Операция не разрешена". Что это может значить?